# Good hash function for unordered set of string?

Tags: go, hash

Is there a method for multiple unordered string sets, in which the string elements are the same.
for example:

`set1 = [ "ab3567cd", "123", "789012" ]`

`set2 = [ "789012", "ab3567cd", "123" ]`

`set3 = [ "123", "789012", "ab3567cd" ]`

And hash these sets return the same result without sorting them.

Is there such a hash function?

Comment: Hash with what language?

Comment: golang language

Answer (score 0):

Without sorting them to have the same position you will get always different hashes.

This are always different strings:

ab3567cd 123 789012

789012 ab3567cd 123

123 ab3567cd 789012

[Do identical strings always have the same SHA-256 value?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/55345/do-identical-strings-always-have-the-same-sha-256-value)

[What is a Hashing Algorithm and How Does it Work?](https://crosstower.com/resources/education/what-is-a-hashing-algorithm-and-how-does-it-work/)

[How does file hashing works?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/168492/how-does-file-hashing-works)

**UPDATE:**

There are two solutions, but i don't now if this is the right way.

**This is only an logical example, it maybe not the right function/count way!**

1. Solution

If i count the values of the set, with the right function.

**set1 = [ "ab3567cd", "123", "789012" ]**

count:

```
 "ab3567cd" (+ or *) "123" (+ or *) "789012" = RESULT_VALUE
```

Than you hash the RESULT_VALUE you will get always the same hash value for set1, set2 and set3.

```
RESULT_HASH = HASH(RESULT_VALUE)
```

2. Solution

**set1 = [ "ab3567cd", "123", "789012" ]**

```
create hash1 from "ab3567cd"

create hash2 from "123"

create hash3 from "789012"
```

Count:

```
hash1 (+ or *) hash2 (+ or *) hash3 = RESULT_VALUE
```

Than you hash the RESULT_VALUE you will get always the same hash value for set1, set2 and set3.

```
RESULT_HASH = HASH(RESULT_VALUE)
```

This logical example works with all languages that can hash.